# How to handle read transaction in Java to provide consistency?

Tags: java, sql, database, transactions, consistency

I am developing a client in `Java`. It communicates with the server via actions. Actions are social-like actions (an example of a action is a user views the profile of another user).

With the View Profile example above, the client executes 4 queries to get the data from the database server. To provide consistency, I want to put the 4 queries in a transaction. So in my View Profile function, first I put `conn.setAutoCommit(false)`, then queries the data, and at the end before return I set auto commit to true again `conn.setAutoCommit(true)` (see the code snippet below).

```
try {
  // set auto commit to false to manually handle transaction
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  // execute query 1 
  // ...

  // execute query 2
  // ...

  // execute query 3
  // ...

  // execute query 4
  // ...

  // set auto commit to true again to not affect other actions
  conn.setAutoCommit(true);
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace(System.out);
} finally {
  try {
    conn.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
}
```

However, when I run the code, sometimes I notice that the data returned from this action is not consistent. When I tries to combine the 4 queries in a single query, I can achieve consistency.

My question is, does setting autoCommit in Java really work with read transaction like in my example, when I want to issue separate queries to the DBMS? If not, how can I provide consistency if I want to query the DBMS in 4 separate queries?

FYI, the database server I use is Oracle DB.

Comment: You may need to set the transaction isolation level.

Comment: Could you explain clearer? How and where to set the level? In the Java client-side or in the Oracle DB server?

Comment: Use Connection.setTransactionIsolation() from your Java code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test and reply the result. Hope it works.

Comment: I tried conn.setTransactionIsolation() with two options Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED and Connection.SERIALIZABLE but both do not work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

For oracle, selects never do dirty reads, so are always implicitly TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED. If you ate ingesting data at a high rate, my guess is that data is changing between the first and last select, so your best bet would be to combine the selects into one using 3 UNIONs.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html

Comment: Thanks. Using Union is a good way to combine multiple SELECTs. I am just wondering if there are some ways to call SELECT separately in the java code and still achieve consistent reads.

Another question is that is there any situation in which we would really need to separate SELECT statements in a single transaction?